# Reading variable from a file, works fine in my terminal, doesn't work in .sh file

Tags: bash, sh

I want to run the following command, to charge the content of a file in an environment variable

```
read var << file.txt
```

When I run it from my terminal it works fine.

But if I run the exact same command from a .sh files, what happens is that it waits for an output, as if I had just written :

```
read var
```

Comment: I"ve never seen using `<<`. Did you try `<` ? Else, the typical pattern is `while read var ; do cmds ..... ; more cmds ... ; done < file`. Good luck.

Comment: `<<` introduces a here document, with the string `file.txt1` as the delimiter. No shell should interpret that as reading the contents of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easy use `cat` to get the content of the file something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
myvar=$(cat file.txt)
echo "$myvar"
```